# Finding the mode of random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

I was solving random questions in my stats textbook and came across this. To find the mode, we need to find the value of $x$ for which $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)<0$. After applying derivative to the pdf, how do we proceed?

Comment: This sure seems random.  What is $f(x)$?  Are you trying to solve a maximum likelihood equation?  If so, under what sampling regime? Or are you just trying to find the $x$ that maximizes $\lambda\exp(-x\lambda)$? Please help by clarifying your problem.

Comment: Nope, just trying to find the mode of X where X is similar to an exponential distribution

Comment: What does "the mode of $X$ where $X$ is similar to an exponential distribution" mean?

Comment: This is the full question: Let X~Expo(λ). Find the mode of X~Expo(λ). I'm just trying to solve to find the mode.

Answer (score 1):

The mode is the $x$ such that the pdf attains its **global** maximum. In general, it is true that "if $f'(x) = 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$, then $x$ is the global maximum of a function".

Let's turn to math.

$$f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \text{for}~ x \in [0, +\infty)$$

$$f'(x) = -\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x}$$

Then:

$$f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow -\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x} = 0 \Rightarrow \text{no $x$ satisfies}~f'(x) = 0.$$

Let's look at $x = 0$:

$$f(0) = \lambda e^{-\lambda \cdot 0} = \lambda > 0.$$

Moreover, notice that:

$$f(x) > 0 ~\forall x \in [0, +\infty),$$

and

$$f'(x) < 0 ~\forall x \in [0, +\infty).$$

This means that this function is always positive and always decreases. Hence, you can conclude that the global maximum is attained at $x=0$. For these reasons, $x=0$ is the mode.